# mySQL - How to Cache a SELECT result / best way to increase performance with large data

Tags: mysql, caching, large-data

So I am developing a system that displays data in visual means over particular timeframes.
In order to display the data - complex queries will be executed with Huuuuuge datasets (possibly even over 1 million records).

Some of the queries will not change (obviously because no more data will be collected within that timeframe). We have already setup a partition system but the problem arises when we want to collect data on 6+ Months worth of data. -  The calculations for a period of each day (with 1000s of records each) for a timeframe of over a year (1000+ * 365+) would consequence in serious performance issues.

~

Originally I was thinking of creating a table for each unique query and have a function that collects and stores data for that day (periodically executed at around 1am each night).
So I would have a table originally looking like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| Item  | StartTime | EndTime | Column1 | Column2 |
---------------------------------------------------
| Item1 | Day1      | Day1    | DataA1  | DataB2  |
| Item2 | ...       | ...     | DataA1  | DataB4  |
| Item1 | ...       | ...     | DataA2  | DataB4  |
| ...   | ...       | ...     | ...     | ...     |
| Item1 | Day2      | Day2    | DataA1  | DataB2  |
| Item2 | ...       | ...     | DataA1  | DataB4  |
| Item1 | ...       | ...     | DataA2  | DataB4  |
| ...   | ...       | ...     | ...     | ...     |
---------------------------------------------------
```

That appends data like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Date  | Item   | AvgTime | MaxTime | OtherComplex | OtherComplex2 | ....... |
|-------+--------+---------+---------+--------------+---------------+---------|
| Day1  | Item1  | 45.22   | 120     | abcdef       | ABCDEF        | ...     |
| ...   | Item2  | ...     | ...     | ...          | ...           | ...     |
| ...   | ...    | ...     | ...     | ...          | ...           | ...     |
| ...   | ...    | ...     | ...     | ...          | ...           | ...     |
| Day2  | Item1  | 16.02   | 24      | defghi       | ABCDEF        | ...     |
| ...   | Item2  | ...     | ...     | ...          | ...           | ...     |
| ...   | ...    | ...     | ...     | ...          | ...           | ...     |
| ...   | ...    | ...     | ...     | ...          | ...           | ...     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I believe this would work but then we would have to maintain more tables - and if we want to add more features to the program then it could get a pain to maintain.

We could use [MySQL Query Cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html) but I believe this refers to queries with static data with 'static' variables - a big part of the system is that we can query between ANY two dates.

~

So what would be the best way to go about this? Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: 1 Million record is far from huuuuuge dataset. you probably need to optimise your schema and/or indexes. 
post an EXPLAIN SELECT [...] result before trying to optimise wrong stuff

Comment: @sathia [link](http://orig13.deviantart.net/63c7/f/2015/182/2/1/explain_select_by_chickenmobile-d8zk4um.jpg) this is a result of a EXPLAIN SELECT on a query that would be used. Please note this is only for one period and the query is around 100 lines long (another 364 of these is needed to display each days data). - The data collected is only for one user of around 5 days worth of data. We expect the data to be at least 2000x bigger.

Comment: Looks like you are not using indexes where the cardinality is bigger. I see that you have blurred some fields but it would really help if you could paste the query and the show create table output of the tables involved. Anyway, a query 100 lines long usually suggests that there's something that can optimised